# Nav bar is shifting

Tags: html, css

Hi I am making web site by using html & css I have problem with my nav bar. texts on the nav bar are shifting when I decrease the browsers size. Here pic

[image]

And my css code:

```
    .menu{
      margin-top:4em;
      width:100%; 
      height:4em;
      font-size:0.813em;
      list-style-type:none;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      position:fixed;

   }
.menu li{
     float:right;
     padding:1em 1em;
     display:inline; 

     }
```

How can I prevent this situation ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your `width` of the navbar and de `list-items`.. When de 5 `list-items` together a wider than the total `width` of the navbar, it can collapse like in you `image`. To prevent this, you could use `min-width`

```
.menu{
    ....
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css media query. For example

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {    
    .h1 {
        font-size: 21px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

And set different width of your navbar for different screen sizes.